# How to fix lock screen stuck at "Tap to speak" when entering password?

Tags: locked-out

I can’t access my phone. When I try to enter my password to unlock my phone it displays "Tap to speak" with microphone and the word "Google". There is also sign of setting and "X" but they are not responding.

This thing blocks me from using my phone and I don't know how it got into my phone. I am not familiar with it. How do I unlock my phone?

Comment: Did you enable 'voice lock' ?

Comment: my kid was playing with my phone I suspect she activated it accidentally

Answer (score 1):

It's not cleared that what lock you used(there are 3rd party and in built 'Voice Lock' which could be found under Security Settings and then one is 'Google Voice Lock').

If it 'Google Voice Lock' say 'Ok Google' & 'Hey Google'. If it is your handset, you would have used Google Voice Search/Google Assistance which only activates by saving your voice.
Same voice is used for 'Google Voice Lock'.

So, if it is this lock. It will unlock as voice matches.

If it is other than this, i found this forum by xda-developers that could help you: [Lock Screen stuck at voice lock.](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2252711)